# Audio recorded in chrome/firefox (other than safari) does not play in safari browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, safari

I have an application which saves audio recording from browser and plays it.

My problem is: audio recorded other than safari browser does not play in safari browser. it gives error on audio play.

But the audio recorded in safari works perfectly fine.

here is html:

```
<audio controls src={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL + voice?.url} type="audio/wav">
            Your browser does not support the
            <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

here is js:

```
navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: {
          sampleRate: 44100,
        },
      })
      .then(function (stream) {
        speech.resume()
        status = 'RECORDING'
        recordingStatus.innerText = 'Recording'
        recordingIcon.src = '/img/mic2.png'
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
        mediaRecorder.start()
        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
          chunks.push(e.data)
        }

        let totalLength = 1
        const totalLengthInterval = setInterval(() => {
          totalLength += 1
        }, 1000)

        const autoStop = setTimeout(() => {
          if (status == 'RECORDING') {
            mediaRecorder.stop()
            subsModal()
          }
        }, activeSubscription.limits.totalSpeechToTextLength * 1000)

        mediaRecorder.onstop = async function (e) {
          let blob = new Blob(chunks, {
            type: 'audio/wav',
            // type: isChrome ? 'audio/wav; codecs=0' : 'audio/ogg;codecs=opus',
          })
          const formData = new FormData()

          formData.append('voice', blob)
          formData.append('noteId', note.id)
          formData.append('clientId', clientId)
          formData.append('length', totalLength)

          const url = '/api/dashboard/note/voice/add'
          const { data } = await axios.post(url, formData)

          if (data.success) {
            message.success(data.descr)
            note.voiceRecords.push(data.voice)
            setVoices(note.voiceRecords.slice(0))
          } else {
            message.error(data.descr, 'Something went wrong')
          }

          recordingStatus.innerText = 'Add'
          recordingIcon.src = '/img/mic1.png'
          status = null
          speech.suspend()
          clearTimeout(autoStop)
          clearInterval(totalLengthInterval)
          stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it with this library https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC.

It is very similar to using the MediaRecorder API, so maybe you can refactor your code easily.